# Some fonts are not anti-aliased when used over HDMI

Tags: fonts, hdmi, antialiasing

I have searched around and have tried various suggestions that are posted, however I cannot get this fixed.

My computer is hooked up through HDMI to my 1080P monitor and the fonts in Chrome, Firefox and various other programs look bad. Other places like the desktop the fonts look good. I think it is an anti-aliasing problem. The fonts look fine if hooked up through RGB however.

I have tried removing the `~/.config/dconf/user` and tried changing the font rendering and hinting.

I have a RadeonHD 5450 and have used both open source and fglrx drivers. I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

You can see from the screenshot, the Software Center fonts are clear, however the browser fonts are not sharp. This is not limited to the browser.

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction, I have been dealing with this for sometime now.

Comment: I keep staring at this picture, but I just don't see it...

Answer (score 2):

Seems to worked its way out, but only after adjusting the pixel format to RGB Limited and changing the GPU scaling under adjustments to maintain aspect ratio in the Catalyst Control Center.

However, when testing the settings back to default the fonts still look great.

Something must have been stuck.